# Can't delete a private hosted zone in AWS Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-route53

I am unable to delete Private Hosted Zone from console and CLI.

Please check below screen shot

[image]

Its throwing following error

> The resource hostedzone/Z346QOK8DECBDU can only be managed through servicediscovery.amazonaws.com (arn:aws:servicediscovery:us-east-1:757712384777:namespace/ns-oekfhwgvesmkdb4i)

Private zone has following records
[image]

I have tried deleting using AWS CLI commands as well

```
aws servicediscovery list-services
aws servicediscovery delete-service --id=ID-FROM-LIST
aws servicediscovery delete-namespace --id=NS-LIST
```

This did not work. I got following error

> An error occurred (NamespaceNotFound) when calling the DeleteNamespace operation: NS-LIST
>
> An error occurred (ServiceNotFound) when calling the DeleteService operation: ID-FROM-LIST

Please let me know if there is any other way.

Comment: *"This did not work."*  What were the errors?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot : I have updated Question with details of error and console screenshot. Please check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to delete the AWS ECS service, which is using this hosted zone from AWS console, and then if you have any service discovery resources (like namespace), then delete those using below commands:

1. Use below command to list services in specific region:

   ```
   aws servicediscovery list-services --region <region_name>
   ```
2. If no services associated, then try to find the namespaces:

   ```
   aws servicediscovery list-namespaces --region <region_name>
   ```
3. Then you can delete the namespace as below:

   ```
   aws servicediscovery delete-namespace --id <service_discovery_namespace_id> --region <region_name>
   ```

From output, It seems you don't have any services listed, but still try with `--region` option.

Your `namespace_id` seems to be incorrectly passed. Its `arn` is already shown in first error message.

**To delete the private hosted zone:**

> To delete a private hosted zone that Amazon ECS created when you created a service using service discovery, delete the Amazon ECS services that are using the namespace, and delete the namespace

Ref:

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zone-private-deleting.html
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/delete-service.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Tried it now. Still same issue. Its showing no services with region parameter as well. same error again. I have gone through the AWS Docs and followed the steps. NS and SOA records inside the private hosted zone are not getting deleted. "Delete Record Set" option is disabled for these 2 records.

Comment: I have deleted the ECS Service as well. No Issues there.

Comment: You are passing the incorrect id for the delete-namespace command. Check the Id.

Comment: There are no services in the list to pass id. Yes in the screenshot it's showing string instead of id.. I just passed it because service list is empty

Comment: @PavanRao What output you get when you run list-namespaces command?

Comment: {
    "Namespaces": [
        {
            "Type": "DNS_PRIVATE", 
            "Id": "ns-oekfhwgvesmkdb4i", 
            "Arn": "arn:aws:servicediscovery:us-east-1:757712384777:namespace/ns-oekfhwgvesmkdb4i", 
            "Name": "local"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: It worked.. Thank you Sangam.. I was concentrating on services rather than namespaces.

Comment: I have updated the question to remove incorrect screenshot without id..

Answer (score 4):

It is very simple if you have access to console

Search for “AWS cloud map” in aws console – > you can see than namespace – go inside namespace -> delete services -> go back and delete namespace -> check in your route53 console, hosted zone wont be there